# Parse: [Error]: object not found for update Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have been struggling with this for hours. Please help! I know there are several posts already about this error but I cannot seem to find a post specific to my problem. I don't get the error until I *sign out* of the current account that I am signed into and *sign into* another account.

```
var prayerRequests = PFObject(className: "PrayerRequests")
var query = PFQuery(className:"PrayerRequests")
var objectId: String?
var allPrayerRequestsArray = [String]()
```

The above code is the variables that are declared outside a function. The code below are declared inside of an `@IBAction`.

```
    self.query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            self.objectId = objects[0].objectId! //returns the id of the 
            //first object in the class which is the object 
            //that holds the allPrayerRequestsArray
            println(self.objectId!)
            self.query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.objectId!, block: { (prayerRequests: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                } else if let prayerRequests = prayerRequests {
                    println(self.allPrayerRequestsArray)
                    prayerRequests["requests"] = self.allPrayerRequestsArray
                    prayerRequests.saveInBackground()
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: The `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is pointless - objects[0] *is* the object you are getting - you have already fetched it with the `find`

Comment: what are you trying to do save or query ?

Comment: @Lamar I am trying to save here with this line of code `prayerRequests["requests"] = self.allPrayerRequestsArray`

Comment: @Paulw11 If I were not to use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId`, then how would I be able to update my `prayerRests["requests"]`?

Comment: but why you are querying ?, what you want to save to parse

Comment: I am querying so that I can get the Id of the first object in the class. So that I can use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` so that I can update my `prayerRequests["requests"]`

Comment: `let prayerRequests = objects[0]   prayerRequest["requests"]=self.allPrayerRequestsArray` - the "find" has already done the "get"

Comment: I want to save to parse, `self.allPrayerRequestsArray`.

Comment: but if you want to save something new to that class , you don't need to query, just override it